# PHP/MSSQL; Inserting records based on whether data exists for an array index

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a PHP form with a structure like the following:

```
<input type="text" name="code[]" id="code[]" value="<?php echo $code[4] ?>" />
<input type="text" name="period[]" id="period[]" value="<?php echo $period[4]; ?>" />
```

There are five rows on my form with this structure. What I'm trying to do is, upon submit, ONLY insert records if the user enters data into these rows. Each row of input will produce a separate record. If the rows are blank, no record should be written. Right now, we have the INSERT statement in a for() loop, and it inserts blank records whenever the indexed field rows are empty. Here is what the INSERT statement looks like right now:

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<=4; $i++) {
    $new = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO table (code, period) VALUES(:code, :period)");
    $data = array('code'=>$_POST['code'][$i],'period'=>$_POST['period'][$i]);
    $new->execute($data);
}
?>
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Neither `code` nor `period` should be empty?  Or one empty is OK?

Comment: Both fields are required, so they either have to both be blank or both have to be filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want insert only non-empty rows from your form, just check if there is something filled:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<=4; $i++) {
    if(isset($_POST['code'][$i]) && $_POST['code'][$i] != '' && 
       isset($_POST['period'][$i]) && $_POST['period'][$i] != ''){
          $new = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO table (code, period)
          VALUES(:code, :period)");
          $data = array('code'=>$_POST['code'][$i],'period'=>$_POST['period'][$i]);
          $new->execute($data);
    }
} 
?>
```

Notice, if you send blank fields they're set (isset returns true) but they are empty strings

Answer (score 1):

For both to be not empty (just change `&&` to `||` if one can be empty):

```
for($i=0; $i<=4; $i++) {
    if(!empty($_POST['code'][$i]) && !empty($_POST['period'][$i]) {
        $new = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO table (code, period) VALUES(:code, :period)");
        $data = array('code'=>$_POST['code'][$i],'period'=>$_POST['period'][$i]);
        $new->execute($data);
    }
}
```